# CloudCompare computed Normals are not aligned in the mesh

Tags: mesh, normals, meshlab, cloudcompare

When I compute normals from CloudCompare software for the PLY file I created from PCL, I am seeing the faces as shown in the picture. The normals are flipped. This issue is similar to the one mentioned in https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1659 .
I observed the same in Meshlab as well. Meshlab has the option to turn on BackFace as double to visualize it similar to PCL visualizer.

[Mesh normals are flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdeLq.png)

This issue occurs when the mesh is generated using pcl Concave Hull method. Not when using the Poisson Surface reconstruction. How do I get it corrected for the concave hull based surface reconstruction?

Answer (score 0):

There is a MeshLab filter named ‘Re-Orient all faces coherently that will re-orient in a consistent way all the faces of the mesh.

The filter visits a mesh face to face, reorienting any unvisited face so that it is coherent to the already visited faces. If the surface is orientable it will end with a consistent orientation of all the faces. If the surface is not orientable (e.g. it is non manifold or non orientable like a moebius strip) the filter will not build a consistent orientation simply because it is not possible. The filter can end up in a consistent orientation that can be exactly the opposite of the expected one; in that case simply invert the whole mesh orientation using the filter ‘Invert Faces Orientation’